# Calculating the number of weeks in a month for a calendar in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, calendar

I have a calendar that shows public events for the month.  It is a responsive layout, so I need to be able to calculate the week_row height.  Therefore, I need to be able to calculate the number of weeks in the month, including partial weeks (weeks that contain days from the current month and the previous/next month).

The following method calculates the number of weeks in the month:

```
def weeks_in_month(date)
  @week_count = (0.5 + (date.end_of_month.day + date.beginning_of_month.wday).to_f / 7.0).round
end
```

and the code to add the appropriate class(es) to the `<div>` is:

```
def week_rows
   weeks.map {|week|
     content_tag :div, class: week_classes(week) do
       week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
     end
   }.join.html_safe
end

def week_classes(date)
  classes = ['week']
  classes << "wk_rows_4" if weeks_in_month(date) == 4
  classes << "wk_rows_5" if weeks_in_month(date) == 5
  classes << "wk_rows_6" if weeks_in_month(date) == 6
  classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
end
```

However, I have missed something.  The week_classes aren't populating anything other than the default `'week'` class.

This is based off of RailsCasts #213, modified as per [this tutorial](http://www.techdarkside.com/creating-a-calendar-with-twitter-bootstrap-without-tables) on creating a calendar without tables, which also borrows heavily from RC#231.

Any idea why it's not assigning the correct class to the `<div>`?

Everything else in the calendar is working.  Here is the complete code:

```
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).calendar_div
  end

  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def calendar_div
       content_tag 'div', id: "calendar" do
          header + week_rows
       end
    end

    def header
       content_tag 'div', id: 'weekdays' do
          HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :div, class: 'weekday' do
             day
          end }.join.html_safe
       end
    end

    def week_rows
       weeks.map {|week|
          content_tag :div, class: week_classes(week) do
             week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
          end
       }.join.html_safe
    end

    def week_classes(date)
       classes = ['week']
       classes << "wk_rows_4" if weeks_in_month(date) == 4
       classes << "wk_rows_5" if weeks_in_month(date) == 5
       classes << "wk_rows_6" if weeks_in_month(date) == 6
       classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def day_cell(day)
       content_tag :div, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
       classes = ['day']
       classes << "today" if day == Date.today
       classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
       classes << "month" if day.month == date.month
       classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def weeks
       first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
       last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
       (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end

    def weeks_in_month(date)
       @week_count = (0.5 + (date.end_of_month.day + date.beginning_of_month.wday).to_f / 7.0).round
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have any tests for the `weeks_in_month` method to show that it is working as expected? Also, what is the instance variable in `weeks_in_month` doing, is that necessary?

Comment: @philnash - No, no tests.  And the instance variable is there just so I can quickly scan the code.  It will be taken out on the first refactor.

The `day_classes` code works, but not the `week_classes`.  That's what's got me stumped.

Comment: Hi @Matteo, in that case I would encourage you to write some tests for the methods that are not working. That way you will likely find what has gone wrong, or at least a starting point for how to fix it.

Comment: @philnash - Yes, you are right.  I should be writing tests for my projects.  I just don't want to have to wrap my head around a new set of syntax just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so some fiddling around lead me to this solution:

```
  def week_rows
     weeks.map {|week|
        content_tag :div, class: week_classes do
           week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
     }.join.html_safe
  end

  def week_classes
     classes = ['week']
     classes << "wk_rows_4" if weeks_in_month == 4
     classes << "wk_rows_5" if weeks_in_month == 5
     classes << "wk_rows_6" if weeks_in_month == 6
     classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
  end

  def weeks_in_month
     (0.5 + (date.end_of_month.day + date.at_beginning_of_month.wday).to_f / 7.0).round
  end
```

It wasn't necessary to pass in `(date)` as a parameter.